# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'message' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

python3 kivy
есть расчетная фнукция и внутри нее результат вычислений записывается в message,при попытке print(message) выходит UnboundLocalError: local variable 'message' referenced before assignment

```
def results(self, btn):
    with open("E:\IT\listfile.txt", "r") as my_file:
        str = my_file.readline()
        a=str
        str = my_file.readline()
        ves=float(str)

        str = my_file.readline()
        rost=float(str)

        str = my_file.readline()
        pol=str

        str = my_file.readline()
        vozrast=float(str)

        str = my_file.readline()
        actyv=str



        if pol == ("Мужчина"):
            message=( 9.99 * ves + 6.25 * rost - 4.92 * vozrast + 5)
        elif pol == ("Женщина"):
            message=(9.99 * ves + 6.25 * rost - 4.92 * vozrast -161)
        if actyv == ("минимум"):
            message=(message*1.2)
        elif actyv == ("слабая"):
            message=(message*1.4)
        elif actyv == ("средняя"):
            message=(message*1.6)
        elif actyv == ("высокая"):
            message=(message*1.8)
        elif actyv == ("экстремальная"):
            message=(message*2.0)
        print(message)
```

Как можно исправить?

---

обьявил значение message перед расчетом принтит только его 
Как исправить?
Пример файла из которого берутся переменные:

Иван

80

170

Мужчина

30

средняя

Comment: очевидно, что если такая ошибка, то ничего туда не записывается, т.к. программа не заходит ни в один if-elif.

Comment: почему,как понять в чем проблема

Comment: из файла читает исправно переменные до расчета проверял принтяться

Comment: посмотреть в данные и сравнить с тем, что написано  в коде.

Comment: попробуйте добавить везде "\n" (символ новой строки), типа "минимум\n"

Comment: обьявил значение message перед расчетом принтит только его

Comment: не понял куда добавить ?

Comment: Приведите пример вашего файла в вопросе. Также вам может помочь, если вы будете выводить все переменные после каждого чтения из файла.